# GridView populating out of order in Leanback

Tags: android, gridview, android-tv, leanback

I'm working to add multiple rows per category to a Leanback (Android TV) project that I'm developing. I am however, seeing odd behavior in the way the rows are populated. The code I'm using works, it was from a tutorial, here:

http://corochann.com/browsefragment-listrow-customization-android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-18-705.html

The rows are loaded by passing them into a custom `Presenter` you create in the tutorial. Here is how that part functions:

```
        int numRows = ((CustomListRow) item).getNumRows();
        ((ListRowPresenter.ViewHolder) holder).getGridView().setNumRows(numRows);

        super.onBindRowViewHolder(holder, item);
```

When the `gridView()` gets populated at runtime, however, it populates the items from Top-to-bottom, rather than left-to-right. Is there a way to fix or adjust that behavior so they are added to the gridvew from left to right like the are supposed to be?

For better reference here are two screenshots. In both screenshots I'm loading the same set of items:

[[1] A normal row. Items load from left-to-right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAVxu.png)

[[2] The multiple row implementation. Items load from top-to-bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKtG4.png)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: I think I ended up overriding the review and changing the behavior that way. It was a while ago though, so I can't be certain.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I saw a different order because the views in some `ViewHolders` had different heights, depending on their content. It may be your case, try to put a fixed height on the `CardView`

Answer (score -2):

Try to read through the [`BrowseFragment ListRow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseFragment.html) it is used to display through a video library. The BrowseFragment class in the Leanback library allows you to create a primary layout for browsing categories and rows of media items with a minimum amount of code. The BrowseFragment basically renders rows of data that you provide.

What I can suggest is for you to scan the documentation on how to create a [Catalog Browser](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/browse.html) and try to follow the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/androidtv-adding-leanback/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2016#0) offered by Google. You'll learn how to quickly enable a mobile app for Android TV using the Leanback library.